# Responsive website inside Iframe on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile

I was having a hard time figuring this out.
I have a responsible website and i was trying to call it by an Iframe.
It worked perfectly on the desktop but it seemed too little on the mobile device.

```
<iframe src="https://religious-freedom.herokuapp.com"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
            iframe:focus {
            outline: none;
        }
        iframe {
            margin: none;
            border: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
        }


        body {
            display: block;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the physical size of the smartphone is wierd.

A viewport controls how a webpage is displayed on a mobile device. Without a viewport, mobile devices will render the page at a typical desktop screen width, scaled to fit the screen. Setting a viewport gives control over the page's width and scaling on different devices.

Pages optimized to display well on mobile devices should include a meta viewport in the head of the document specifying

> width=device-width, initial-scale=1.

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Great answer. I would say that IOs and Androids have different behaviors for iFrames. You need to do a lot of tests in both to make sure you have the results you want